RTL8153 without EEPROM
I am making a usb hub board with built-in ethernet to USB feature with RTL8153.
Similar to the following post I found the datasheet does not say anything regarding how to program the eeprom or if it is okay to use it without eeprom. Maybe, the program and firmware are provided to the contracted manufacturers only.
USB to Ethernet controller, RTL8153, without EEPROM and only 3.3 V
Is it possible to use it without eeprom? Has anyone used it before?

Does section 6.4. EEPROM Interface in the RTL8153 Datasheet help?

@Chester Yes, perfect. Thanks!

The RTL8153 has internal OTP (one-time programmable) memory eFuse that allows use without an external EEPROM. The eFuse memory also tells the RTL8153 what kind of EEPROM to expect.
There will be additional documentation associated with that, and probably not accessible to other than serious customers who sign an NDA. Even the datasheet Olimex has provided (linked above) is marked "CONFIDENTIAL: Development Partners Only".

The Olimex USB-GIGABIT product page has a download for a Windows software tool for changing MAC which looks to be a Realtek provided tool for changing the EEPROM contents when a RTL8153 is connected via a USB to a Windows PC.

Thanks! The Olimex tool worked. This is probably what I was looking for.
